# php echo in form is not working

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, echo

my code doesnt seem to work.. the radio buttons appear but nothing beside them .. it seems as if the mysql_fetch_row is not working for some reason as i have played about with the code and replaced $qnumber to a value manually and tested it however nothing appeared. could someone please advise what is wrong? cheers ps. i am new at this.

this is my code.

```
<?php

include 'dbyear2.php';

$qnumber = ($_REQUEST['uqn']); // obtain question number from URL

$find = mysqli_query($condbyear2, "SELECT * FROM Renal WHERE UQN='$qnumber'");

 while($retrieve=mysqli_fetch_row($find));
 {

      $question = $retrieve['question'];
      $a = $retrieve['MCQ_A']; 
       $b = $retrieve['MCQ_B'];
      $c = $retrieve['MCQ_C'];
         $d = $retrieve['MCQ_D'];
      $e = $retrieve['MCQ_E'];
     $answer = $retrieve['answer'];
       $correct = $retrieve['MCQ_correct'];


       }




      ?>


        <form action='check.php' method='POST'>  

    <table> 

  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr></tr>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' name='group1' value='A' /></td><td> <?php echo $a; ?></td></tr>
       <tr><td><input type='radio' name='group1' value='B' /></td><td> <?php echo $b; ?></td></tr>
         <tr><td><input type='radio' name='group1' value='C' /></td><td> <?php echo $c; ?></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type='radio' name='group1' value='D' /></td><td> <?php echo $d; ?></td></tr>
       <tr><td><input type='radio' name='group1' value='E' /></td><td> <?php echo $e; ?></td></tr> 
   <tr>

      <?php 

     // sending the retrieved information from MYSQL via POST for use in check.php file

    $qnumber;
  $a;
   $b;
     $c;
  $d;
    $e;
  $answer;
    $correct;


   ?></tr>
         <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>





     </table>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Remove the `;` at the end of the while statement

2) `mysqli_fetch_row` returns an enumerated array. What you require is an associative array so you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysqli_fetch_array` instead.

```
while($retrieve=mysqli_fetch_assoc($find))
{
....
```

Comment: Check whether $a .... $e are set. If not check whether any rows are being returned with `mysqli_num_rows()`. Also, have you tried running this query with the manual `$qnumber` in a mysql console or phpmyadmin?

Comment: $a ....$e are not set. i tried to echo them outside teh form and it didnt work. no rows are being returned with mysqli_num_rows(). i used phpmyadmin to run the mysql query and it found the row with no problems.

Comment: apologies. it has found the row using mysqli_num_rows(). evyerthing else written above is correct though

Comment: That took a while. Further reading http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: thank you for your help. i have found out why it's not working.